# Send Gmail SMTP Message from Application EC2 AWS Hosted

Tags: browser, amazon-ec2, ssh, gmail, character

I'm wrote an java application that send Gmail SMTP messages from AWS EC2 Ubuntu, the problem is that google blocks any connection not authorized, Google delivery a page, to access from a browser, that enable access to Gmail from same IP of page access, but in EC2 Ubuntu there is no browser to SSH character environment. There are some way to set server ip to some Gmail permition list?

Answer (score 0):

Just use AWS simple mail service instead.